# MinMax algorithm, choose between movement and attack

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, artificial-intelligence, game-development, minmax

I have an XCOM like game, just much simplier. You can move on the tiles, or attack if the enemy in range. My problem is, I have a MinMax algorithm, and have a move HashSet, and I go trough with a for loop. But these are just the movement. I have another HashSet for the attacks (because the attack range is different than the movement range). How can I implement to choose between combat and movement? Create beneath the movement loop and inside call another minmax? Or do another for loop inside the movement loop?

```
if (depth == 0 || GM.checkWin() != 0)
    {
        return GM.evaluateScore(map) ;
    }
    HashSet<Node> moves = map.getActualMovementOptions();
    HashSet<Node> attacks = map.getUnitAttackOptions();

    if (maxPlayer)
    {
        double bestScore = double.MinValue;
        foreach (Node m in moves)
        {
            map.doMove(m);
            double score = minimax(map, false, depth - 1, alpha, beta);
            Debug.Log("score :" + score);
            
            map.redoMove(m);
            bestScore = Math.Max(score, bestScore);
            alpha = Math.Max(alpha, bestScore);
            Debug.Log("bestscroe: " + bestScore);
            if (beta <= alpha)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        return bestScore;
```

Answer (score 0):

Not an expert in this topic but basically you have to chose one option of the two hashsets .. they have the same type so you could just combine both into a single one and do e.g.

```
HashSet<Node> moves = map.getActualMovementOptions();
moves.UnionWith(map.getUnitAttackOptions());
```

now all items are in the `moves` set and you can just pick the best fit.

I think a main challenge is rather finding good scores for chained actions. Like a move that enables or improves subsequent attack would have higher score e.g.